# Is it possible to regenerate Storage account keys using C#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage-account

I want regenerate Storage account key using C# code and replace old keys in key vault with regenerated key . Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent` and `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent` packages, below is my code to regenerate the key.

```
        string clientSecret = "client secret";
        string clientId = "client id";

        var azureCredentials = new AzureCredentials(new ServicePrincipalLoginInformation
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            ClientSecret = clientSecret
        }, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

        var azure = Azure
        .Configure()
        .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
        .Authenticate(azureCredentials)
        .WithDefaultSubscription();

        var keyName = "key1";

        var storageAccount = azure.StorageAccounts.GetByResourceGroup("resource group name", "storage account name");

        var key = storageAccount.RegenerateKey(keyName);
        Console.WriteLine(key.FirstOrDefault()?.Value);
```

Comment: is it possible to do same with cognitive services key ? if yes , can you please help help me. @George Chen

Comment: Maybe you could post a new question.

Comment: yeah sure @George Chen

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll have to go with the [Azure Rest API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/).

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/regeneratekey) the link describing the call to regenerate the keys of a given Storage Account.